# Texture wrapping mode for KHA

Tags: image, haxe

I'm working on a game engine which is written in Haxe with the Kha API.
I need to set a texture to wrap mode but I can't find any function or variable to use/set.

The image is created with these parameters:

```
    var res = getVoxelRes();
    var resZ =  getVoxelResZ();
    t.width = res;
    t.height = res;
    t.depth = Std.int(res * resZ);
    t.is_image = true;
    path.createRenderTarget(t);
```

path is from the armory3d engine and is ultimately a call to KHA's        `Image.create3D`

Comment: Can you show how you're currently loading and applying the texture?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question.